# How to write a query for this two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

```
EMPLOYEE(id,emp_name)
1, John
2, Michael
3, Philip
```

===================

```
RANK(id,emp_id,date,rank)
1,1,1583413078445,SE
2,1,1583413087085,SSE
3,1,1583413092169,PM
4,2,1583413131802,SE
5,3,1583413536655,SE
```

I want to show

employee id, employee name and latest Rank (whose id is maximum for emp_id in rank table or whose longdate is maximum for emp_id in rank table)  from Rank table

```
id,name,Rank
1, John, PM
2, Michael, SE
3, Philip, SE
```

I am using java and my database is mysql and sqlite (in case offline)
I tried some way but could not aggregate the queries.

Comment: Why PM for John and not SSE or SE?

Comment: @stickybit, because Rank table latest entry for John (emp_id=1) is PM

Comment: And how would you know which one is the latest? You'd need a columns to sort by. A table in a relational database has no order per se.

Comment: @stickybit, there is two column for that in Rank table, max(id) for emp_id, or max(longdate) for emp_id

Comment: The maximum of a bunch of string reading "longdate" is "longdate", so any of them...

Comment: long date is like 1583413078445, I am storing date as long.

Comment: Which is still one value. I think you may want to revise that question and improve the explanation of what you have (actual table DDL and DML might be helpful), want, have tried (actual code would be helpful) and what the problems you faced with that tries (error messages, unexpected results, etc.).

Comment: Not one value, all are different. Every entry will be different value

Comment: They aren't different in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, because table is bigger than that. So I just said those are long value. this is long time in millis. So it will all be different.

Comment: What did you try so far, and what result (different than desired) did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT RK.emp_id, EP.emp_name, RK.rank
FROM RANK RK
LEFT JOIN employee EP ON RK.emp_id=EP.id
GROUP BY RK.emp_id
HAVING MAX(RK.id);
```

Comment: can you keep employee as base table, and then join rank table.? Now if employee id is not in rank table then this employee is not coming in query.

Comment: @AndroidWorld use same query, but, replace Left Join --> Right Join, should work !

Answer (score 1):

What you need is some techniques on analytic functions.

```sql
with RANK_EXPAND as (
  select
    id,emp_id,date,Rank,
    max(date) over (partition by emp_id) as maxDate,
    max(id) over (partition by emp_id, date) as maxId,
  from RANK
),
select
  r.id,
  e.emp_name as name,
  r.Rank
from
  EMPLOYEE e inner join RANK_EXPAND r on e.id=r.emp_id
where
  r.date=r.maxDate and r.id=r.maxId
```

You may also use purely group by + rejoining, but that will make the query much longer.

Comment: Need one signle query. Also with RANK_EXPAND, how to execute this in sqlite.

Comment: The above is a single query...or you mean you cannot use WITH?
BTW, you tag both mysql and sqlite, which one are you using?

Comment: @AndroidWorld just a reminder, I think the Aditya Rewari works as long as RANK.date has the same ordering as the RANK.id. If this assumption does not hold, that answer does not handle your "take max date" requirement.

Comment: Rank.Id is autoincrement primary key. So as long as date is later one, id will also be later one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution of Aditya as the best solution (I would comment the answer, but I don't have necessary reputation).
I just want to point out another possible solution for this using a sub-query in the projection-clause.

```
SELECT EP.emp_id, EP.emp_name, 
(SELECT RK.Rank FROM Rank RK WHERE RK.emp_id=EP.emp_id ORDER BY RK.id DESC LIMIT 1) as Rank
FROM employee EP
;
```